# Does "yum clean all" remove symlinks?

Tags: yum, symlink

I am running confluent upgrade playbooks to upgrade the version.  My OS is RHEL 7 and I have installed Python 3.9 and created a symlink to it from /usr/bin directory.

When running the confluent playbook, it has a Task `yum-clean-all` followed by below tasks

- Custom Java Install
- Install Java
- ...
- ...
- Install pip
- Upgrade pip
- Install pip packages

The playbook failed at Install `pip packages` and after that ansible is not available.

Get this error -

```
ansible --version

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ansible", line 34, in <module>
    from ansible import context
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ansible'
```

Also the symlink to python3 from /usr/bin is also missing at this point.

And in the `/var/log/yum.log`, I see the below at the time that my playbook had failure

```
Jan 04 14:50:44 Installed: python3-setuptools-39.2.0-10.el7.noarch
Jan 04 14:50:44 Installed: python3-pip-9.0.3-8.el7.noarch
Jan 04 14:50:44 Installed: python3-3.6.8-21.el7_9.x86_64
Jan 04 14:50:46 Installed: python3-libs-3.6.8-21.el7_9.x86_64
```

So, I am suspecting that `yum clean all` removed the links, but have not been able to find anything that confirms this suspicion.

So, the question is - Does `yum clean all` remove the symlinks.  Is there any documentation regarding that?

If that is not the cause, I need to dig deeper to find out what is happening

Appreciate any pointers

**Update**

Confluent playbook for this part

```
---
- name: Ensure Custom Repo file is not in repos when repository_configuration is Confluent
  file:
    state: absent
    path: /etc/yum.repos.d/custom-confluent.repo
  when:
    - repository_configuration == 'confluent'
    - installation_method == "package"

- name: Add Confluent Repo file
  template:
    src: confluent.repo.j2
    dest: /etc/yum.repos.d/confluent.repo
    mode: 0644
  register: confluent_repo_result
  until: confluent_repo_result is success
  retries: 5
  delay: 90
  when:
    - repository_configuration == 'confluent'
    - installation_method == "package"

- name: Ensure Confluent Repo file is not in repos when repository_configuration is Custom
  file:
    state: absent
    path: /etc/yum.repos.d/confluent.repo
  when:
    - repository_configuration == 'custom'

- name: Add Custom Repo file
  copy:
    src: "{{custom_yum_repofile_filepath}}"
    dest: /etc/yum.repos.d/custom-confluent.repo
    mode: 0644
  register: custom_repo_result
  until: custom_repo_result is success
  retries: 5
  delay: 90
  when: repository_configuration == 'custom'

# Not using handler because of https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/41313
- name: yum-clean-all
  command: yum clean all
  args:
    warn: false
  register: yum_clean_result
  until: yum_clean_result is success
  retries: 5
  delay: 90
  when: >
    confluent_repo_result.changed|default(False) or
    repository_configuration == 'custom'

- name: Custom Java Install
  include_tasks: custom_java_install.yml

- name: Install Java
  yum:
    name: "{{redhat_java_package_name}}"
    state: present
  register: java_install_result
  until: java_install_result is success  or ansible_check_mode
  retries: 10
  delay: 5
  when: install_java|bool
  tags: package

- name: Install OpenSSL and Unzip
  yum:
    name:
      - openssl
      - unzip
  tags: package

- name: Get Java Version
  shell: java -version
  register: version_output
  check_mode: false
  changed_when: false

- name: Print Java Version
  debug:
    msg: "Current Java Version is: {{version_output.stderr_lines[0]}}"

- name: Install pip
  yum:
    name:
      - python3-pip
    state: present
  become: true
  tags: package

- name: Upgrade pip
  ansible.builtin.pip:
    name: pip
    extra_args: --upgrade
  tags: package

- name: Install pip packages
  ansible.builtin.pip:
    name: "{{pip_packages}}"
  tags: package
```

Comment: No, `yum clean all` clears the `yum` cache and would not delete system files.  The package `python3-3.6.8-21.el7_9.x86_64` would have replaced whatever you had at `/usr/bin/python3`.  The lesson here is to not try to update the system Python, but install whatever versions you need without disrupting the system Python and use virtual environments.

Comment: Thank you.  I had not replaced the system version, I had added 3.9 and changed the symlink for python3.  We need to use ansible 2.11 and Last time when we tried virtual environment with ansible, it did not work.  Hence I tried to install it separately and just changed the symlink.  I have to find a different way now, I guess

Comment: I have added the Confluent provided playbook that seemed to cause my problem.  Do not know why the python3 link was deleted from the above tasks.  Wondering if the `python3-pip` part in `Install pip` task did it